# How to use css method of rotation in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rotation

When my webpage is first loaded, my starting div rotates using this CSS code:

```
    @keyframes rotate
    {
    from {    transform:rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(0deg); 
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); }

    to {    transform:rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(360deg); 
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes rotate 
    {
    from {    transform:rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(0deg); 
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); }

    to {    transform:rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(360deg); 
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); }
    }
```

After the rotation, this code is useless.
I would like it so when a button is clicked, it will make this rotation again.
To do this I need to be able to put this css code into a `javascript/jQuery` function so I can call it at any time.
Is this possible?

Comment: Add the class that applies the animation on click of your button and listen for the matching event to remove it again.

Comment: use jquery .css() function.Note it doesn't support by IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY THIS

```
   $({deg: 0}).animate({deg: d}, {
            duration: 2000,
            step: function(now){
                elem.css({
                     transform: "rotate(" + now + "deg)"
                });
            }
        });
```

Look at [**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/UB2XR/167/)

Comment: Thanks, I should defiintely be able to work from what you've given me there

Answer (score 2):

by simply applying the CSS properties and the desired values to jQuery

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/ufOMAgu/2/edit)

```
$(' #box ').css({
    transition: '2s linear',
    transform: 'rotate(360deg)'
});
```

<sub>P.S: jQuery will handle all those -browser-specific prefixes for you.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your animation behavior into a class like:

```
.rotate{
  -webkit-animation: rotate 4s;
  /* more prefixes if you want to */
  animation: rotate 4s;
}
```

Then you can apply that class on click of your button like:

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
  $('#myElementToAnimate').addClass('rotate');
});
```

To remove the class once your animation has finished you have to listen for the `animationend` event like:

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
  // all the different event names are due to the fact that this isn't fully standardized yet
  $('#myElementToAnimate').addClass('rotate').on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend MSAnimationEnd', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('rotate');
  });
});
```

This should give you smoother results than using JavaScript based animation. See **[this demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zKe8A/3/)**